# Rate of convergence for sequences

Tags: numerical-methods

I have numerically determined that the sequence $\{f_x\} = \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$ approaches $1$ (as $x$ approaches $0$) faster than the sequence $\{g_x\} = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$. However, I am stuck for determing the rate of convergence of each sequence.

Should I use the small angle approximation $\sin(x)\approx x$ and the fact that $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$? Thanks.

Comment: Have you compared them via $f_x\over g_x$?  Also, I am assuming you are comparing them as $x\to 0$?

Comment: Shouldn't they be compared as $|f_x-1|$ and $|g_x-1|$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Taylor expansion:
$$
f_x=\frac{1}{x^2}\Bigl(x^2-\frac{x^6}{6}+O(x^{10})\Bigr)=1-\frac{x^4}{6}+O(x^8).
$$

$$
g_x=\frac{1}{x^2}\Bigl(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^{5})\Bigr)^2=1-\frac{x^2}{3}+O(x^4).
$$

Added detail on the expansion of $g_x$:

$$
\Bigl(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^{5})\Bigr)^2=x^2-2\cdot x\cdot\frac{x^3}{6}-2\cdot x\cdot O(x^5)+\frac{x^6}{36}+O(x^{10})=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+O(x^6)
$$

Comment: Okay. But $\{f_x\}$ is supposed to converge to $1$ faster than $\{g_x\}$, and this expansion doesn't seem to show that?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I expanded your expression for $\{g_x\}$ but I got $O(x^8)$. Could you please show more work for your second line?

Comment: So does this mean that $\{f_x\}$ converges faster because it is $O(x^8)$?

Comment: No. The important terms are $x^4$ in $f_x$ and $x^2$ in $g_x$:$$\frac{f_x-1}{g_x-1}=\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4).$$

Comment: SO can I say that $\{f_x\}$ converges to $1$ at a quartic rate faster than $\{g_x\}$? How would I word this properly?

Comment: You could say that $f_x-1$ converges to $0$ as $x^4$, which is faster than $x^2$, the rate of convergence of $g_x-1$. Or that $(f_x-1)/(g_x-1)$ converges to $0$ as $x^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with the definition of rate of convergence of functions (There is also definition of rate of convergence of sequences):

> Definition. Let $f$ be a function defined on the interval $(a,b)$ that
>   contains $x=0$, and suppose $\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)=L}$. If there exists a
>   function $g$ for which $\lim_{x\to 0}{g(x)=0}$ and a positive constant
>   $K$ such that $$|f(x)-L| \le K|g(x)|$$ for all sufficiently small
>   values of $x$, then $f(x)$ is said to converge to $L$ with **rate of
>   convergence** $O(g(x))$.

Let $f(x)=\sin{x^2}/{x^2}$ and $g(x)=(\sin{x})^2/{x^2}$. From Taylor's Theorem, we know that

$$\sin{x}=x-\frac{1}{6}x^{3}\cos{\xi}$$

for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$. Hence,

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-\frac{1}{6}x^{6}\cos{\xi}}{x^2}=1-\frac{1}{6}x^{4}\cos{\xi}$$

We know $\sin{x}=(1-\cos{2x})/{2}$ and

$$\cos{x}=1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{24}x^4\cos{\xi}$$

for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$. Therefore,

$$g(x)=\frac{(1-1+2x^2-\frac{2}{3}x^4\cos{\xi})/2}{x^2}=\frac{x^2-\frac{1}{3}x^4\cos{\xi}}{x^2}=1-\frac{1}{3}x^2\cos{\xi}$$

Finally

$$|\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x^2}-1|=\frac{1}{6}|x^{4}\cos{\xi}|\le \frac{1}{6}|x^{4}|$$

and

$$|\frac{(\sin{x})^2}{x^2}-1|=\frac{1}{3}|x^2\cos{\xi}|\le \frac{1}{3}|x^2|$$

It follows that the rate of convergence of $f(x)$ is $O(x^4)$ and the rate of convergence of $g(x)$ is $O(x^2)$. It is common to express this in shorthand by writing
$$\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x^2}=1+O(x^4) \qquad and \qquad \frac{(\sin{x})^2}{x^2}=1+O(x^2)$$
That means an error term with rate of convergence $O(x^4)$ approaches zero faster than an error term with rate of convergence $O(x^2)$, as the value of $x$ approaches zero. Therefore $f(x)$ approaches one faster than $g(x)$ as $x$ approaches zero.

Source: A Friendly Introduction to Numerical Analysis by Brian Bradie.

Comment: i wish i could have a copy of the book too.

Comment: You can find it online for free.